# How to include all files of a directory with cmake?

Tags: build-automation, cmake

I want to try CMake to manage a new C++ project. However, some files are automatically generated. I have no way to know the name of the generated files. The only thing I know is that these files are all generated in the foo/ directory. Is there a way to ask CMake to include all .cpp files from foo/ ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may do this with `GLOB`

```
FILE(GLOB ALL_CPP_SRCS *.cpp)
```